# File is not defined Nuxt 2, Rails 6 API activestorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nuxt.js, rails-activestorage

I have used the activestorage library with Vue 2 before successfully. However can't make it work with Nuxt.

I tried different versions and with both @rails/activestorage and activestorage dependencies. Always throws the error:

[image]

It's a headless nuxt app and I want to use activestorage DirectUpload for a file upload component.

Comment: What is a headless Nuxt app? Also, do you have the code related to the error?

Comment: what did you come up with? `File` does not exist on the server-side...

Comment: Sorry @kissu - by headless Nuxt app I meant a decoupled front-end that can consume a RoR backend API but neither are dependend on eachother.

Comment: @RainbowGiantSquid Yeah, such things are indeed usually self-independent. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the activestorage package that needs transpiling on build in nuxt.
It is possible in Nuxt 2 to specify packages to be transpiled by Babel on build, this can be added to nuxt.config.js in build.transpile object like so:

```
  build: {
    ...,
    transpile: [
      '@rails/activestorage',
      ...
    ]
  }
```